# Backup and Restore Centos 7 using Dump

Tags: backup, centos7, backup-restoration, dump

I am very new in Linux.

I have some applications installed in one of my CentOS 7 VPX. I want move my hosting to another provider, so I want create backup of my full system so I can restore it in the new hosting.

I have found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/120431/how-to-backup-a-full-centos-server) on this same site, but I have some doubts.

What is

> blowfish user@backupserver.example.com

?

Where can I find backup file `dump.gz` and how to download it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`-c blowfish` is instructing the ssh command to use blowfish as the communications cipher. `user@backupserver.example.com` is telling ssh to connect to an external account, username `user` on the listed server. You will need to replace this with an account that you have access to if you want to store the backup elsewhere. The full name of the output file is not `dump.gz` but includes the server name and a datestamp.

I would suggest reading the full post along with the man pages to dump, rsync, and ssh before posting any more questions. You have the information available to you already.

Comment: user@backupserver.example.com does not require password here? Thanks

Comment: Depends on if you set up PKI authentication on the account.