# How to restore from .dump.gz file using dump tool?

Tags: centos, backup, backup-restoration, database-backup

I have taken a dump of my server using the following command

`/sbin/dump -0uan -f - / | gzip -2 | ssh -p ***** -c blowfish dev***@***.**.**.** dd of=/DATA/junkBEN/server-full-backup-`date '+%d-%B-%Y'`.dump.gz`

This was suggested in this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/120431/how-to-backup-a-full-centos-server)

However it does not say how to restore using the `.gz` file. Can someone guide me how to do so please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The dump command referred to is piped to `gzip` to be compressed. It's the `gzip` command you want. Decompress gzip files with this command:

```
gzip -d <filename>
```

Once the file decompressed, use the restore command to restore the dump. Depending on situation, maybe best to restore to a new directory to check the restored files veracity rather than overwrite the originals.

```
restore -f <decompressed-filename>
```

Comment: It says `restore: /dev/tape: No such file or directory` even when I run it in the same directory any idea why?

Comment: Presumably /dev/tape was mounted when the backup was made, and it is not mounted when the restore was done. It does not mean necessarily that the restore has failed.

Comment: ok Iam here now `restore > ` after I typed `restore -i -f <filename>`. Whats next? I have no clue

Comment: Don't use `-i` it is interactive mode for selective restore. Answer edited.

Comment: which one should I use then